# Removing elements from list with condition (VB)

Tags: vb.net, list, while-loop

I have a list

```
 Dim list As New List(Of Double)
```

I want to remove the last entries, if the differences are > 20.

My idea to check the last 30 entries:

```
   Do While index >= list.Count - 30

        If Math.Sqrt((list(index) - list(index + 1)) ^ 2) > 20 Then

            list.RemoveAt(index)
            
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

It does not lead to my solution. Can somebody help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, let me understand better. Suppose you have a list of 50 doubles. You want to remove starting from the end of the list all elements that have the condition from your code satisfied and at the first double that doesn't satisfy the condition you would stop the loop (even if there are other elements that satisfy the condition in lower indexes)?

Comment: exactly steve. sorry for not describing it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a List of doubles I would use a LinkedList of doubles to make use of the class methods and properties like AddFirst, Last, Last.Previous

So let's assume that you have a LinkedList declared like

```
Dim list As New LinkedList(Of Double)
```

And you have added elements to this list using

```
list.AddFirst(134.5678)
```

Now, you could remove from the end of the list with something like this

```
' You want to have a list of at least 30 elements
Do While list.Count > 30

    ' Last node and the previous one
    Dim dLast = list.Last
    Dim dLastPrev = list.Last.Previous

    ' Evaluate the two elements
    If Math.Sqrt(dLastPrev.Value - dLast.Value) ^ 2 > 20 Then
        ' Remove the last and continue to evaluate the next pair
        list.RemoveLast()
    Else
        ' Stop if the condition is not met.
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Of course this could also be done using your current list type.
Also notice how I have swapped the two elements to verify. This is done to avoid any possibility of an IndexOutOfRangeException

```
Dim index as Integer = list.Count - 1
Do While index >= list.Count - 30

    Dim prev = index - 1
    If Math.Sqrt((list(prev) - list(index)) ^ 2) > 20 Then
        list.RemoveAt(index)
    else
        Exit Do
    End If
    index = index - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much steve, it works fine now! For some reason, I had to declare
Dim index As Integer = list.Count - 1
Otherwise I get the IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Correct, I have not tested the second example.